# signed apk not working on my device

Tags: android, keystore, sign

I have signed my .apk with the export signed apk wizard in the manifest, I am trying to deploy it on my device but it doesn't work even there's no problem happened in the signing process, when I install it on my device it started to install and it stop showing me (application not installed).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nazzelha.elfagr"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- Mobclix Required Permissions " -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<!-- Mobclix Optional Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FeedsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity3"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".InfoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <!-- Twitter -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.PrepareRequestTokenActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="callback"
                android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Mobclix and AdMob Required Parameter -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.mobclix.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ID" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
        android:value="ID" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.mobclix.android.sdk.MobclixBrowserActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have saved your App with .apk extension while signing process??

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO,you should take more time when asking a question,you should provide useful and clear logs,and explain in detail what is your problem so other users can help you better.[How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: Hi @sokie there's no logs or bit of code everything is working but that's the problem it doesn't install on my device showing this message

Comment: uninstall old app and install new signed app again

Comment: @AndroSelva  I have edited the question to be more clear

Comment: You should try cleaning your code from eclipse Project-clean and then try to create your apk again

Comment: @sokie  I cleaned it and re-install it it shows an error message after installing it on the device " The application package installer (process com.android.packageinstaller) has stopped unexpectedly"

Comment: I edited my question and I added manifest file

Answer (score 0):

### You need to uninstall the app that's on your phone first, then you'll be able to install from your .apk

Now that I know the error you're getting, the problem is a little more strange..
I've found a similar problem [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6719). According to the last comment, his problem was a bad line on androidmanifest.xml. Maybe you should check your manifest to see if everything's ok.

Comment: after I uninstalled it and install the new signed .apk it installed but it shows me that error message " The application package installer (process com.android.packageinstaller) has stopped unexpectedly